# a real wow with / a real wow for / a real wow among

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, british-english

The first sentence is from Cambridge dictionary. As I understand the first one - "He" has good relationships with all the girls from his class. Right? Is it because of his behavior with the girls, or is it just the girls' dreams and impressions?

Are the second and the third ones possible? What's the difference in meaning between them?

> He's **a real wow with** the girls in his class.
>
> He's **a real wow for** the girls in his class.
>
> He's **a real wow among** the girls in his class.

Comment: It might mean that they find him attractive or thrilling, or just that they like his manner. There's no implication about any relationship.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty, I'm trying to understand what prepositions can be used with this meaning of "he is a real wow ..." If the girls find him attractive, why here not used "for" or "among"?

Comment: We generally say 'a wow **with** [one or more people]'.